# Variables in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a basic template which displays the emails and corresponding domains from a CSV file.

My emails.html file is:

```
<html>
<head>Emails</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for email in email_list %}
        <li> {{email}} </li>
        <li> {{domain}} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
```

And my views.py file is:

```
def emails(request):
    f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/emails.csv')
    email_list = f.read().split()
    # domain = email.split('@')[1]
    return render_to_response('emails.html', {'email_list':email_list, 'domain':domain})
```

What is the correct way to reference the 'email' variable contained in the html file? For example, if I was doing the function in one script, I would have it as:

```
for emails in 'list of emails':
    domain = emails.split('@')[1]
    print emails, domain
```

What is the correct expression to use in views.py to express this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to do f.close() after you read the file otherwise your file will not be closed. The best way to ensure the file is closed is to do "with open('/file') as f:".

Comment: the f.close() should go after the email_list line?

Comment: Yes. I would use a with statement instead though. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom filter [as described here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#template-filters-that-expect-strings)

E.g.,:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='domain')
@stringfilter
def domain(value):
    if '@' in value:
        return value.split('@')[1]
```

Usage (assuming the templatetags module you're using is called email_tags.py):

```
{% load email_tags %}
<html>
<head>Emails</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for email in email_list %}
        <li> {{email}} </li>
        <li> {{email|domain}} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
```

You would create a `templatetags` directory in your app (and make sure to add a `__init__.py` file so it's a module).

This may seem overkill, but it's a very useful way to add power to Django templates.

Comment: Where do I save the custom filter?

Comment: In your app directory, create a `templatetags` directory with a blank `__init__.py` and the `email_tags.py` file with the code above. Make sure your app is in the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Comment: Thank you! Also, from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter also needs to be included in the emails_tags.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the domain parsing in the view if you don't like template tags (I don't like template tags)

```
def emails(request):
  f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/emails.csv')
  email_list = f.read().split()
  email_domain_set = []  # a list of dictionaries
  for email in email_list:
    #guard against data integrity problems (i.e. email doesn't have an @)
    try:
      email_domain_dict = {"email":email, "domain": email.split('@')[1]}
      email_domain_set.append(email_domain_dict)        
    except IndexError:
      pass
      # if we want to see errors, but not fail, could do that like this 
      #email_domain_dict = {"email":email, "domain": "ERROR"}
      #email_domain_set.append(email_domain_dict)        

  return render_to_response('emails.html', {'email_domain_set':email_domain_set})
```

Then in your template

```
<html>
<head>Emails</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for item in email_domain_set %}
        <li> {{item.email}} </li>
        <li> {{item.domain}} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Template tags may seem like a lot of work for something this simple, but it keeps both your view code and template code very clean.

Comment: They do, but they also add complexity to the project structure.  So it is a trade-off - simple project or simple view.  The template is more or less a wash.

Comment: A project of any decent size will eventually benefit from custom template tags/filters. Might as well use them sooner than later since it will keep your view business logic clean, and the templatetags structure will be there when you need it for next time.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree.  I can think of a few cases where I'd rather add the complexity to my views, and I've had rather large projects that never needed custom template tags.  That said, I've already shared that I have a bias against template tags